# Global Shortcut Key Not Working MacOS - HotKey

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, hotkeys

I am attempting to implement a shortcut key "Command + Option + J" using HotKey and for some reason it wont work outside the view controller. The app is implemented as a menu bar drop down so there isn't an actual window to bring to the front. I am expecting my message to be printed though. I have two buttons, register and unregister, when I register and I print out the keycombo I see it has been registered so I believe that is working. Unfortunately though when I press the combo keys while another window is open or on the desktop view, no comment is printed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import Cocoa
import AppKit
import HotKey
import Carbon

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pressedLabel: NSTextField!
    
    private var hotKey: HotKey? {
        didSet {
            guard let hotKey = hotKey else {
                pressedLabel.stringValue = "Unregistered"
                return
            }

            pressedLabel.stringValue = "Registered"
            hotKey.keyDownHandler = { [weak self] in
            NSApplication.shared.orderedWindows.forEach({ (window) in
               print("woo")
            })
            }
    }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        register(self)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func unregister(_ sender: Any?) {
        hotKey = nil
        print("the hot key is ", hotKey?.keyCombo)

        
    }
    

    @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {
        hotKey = HotKey(keyCombo: KeyCombo(key: .j, modifiers: [.command, .shift])
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Where can we find `HotKey`?

Comment: https://github.com/soffes/HotKey

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a **reference problem**:

```
private var hotKey: HotKey?
```

The `HotKey` configuration is meant to stay alive. It handled global key press events and then calls the callback. If you put it into the view controller, and then remove the view controller's window from screen or otherwise have it deallocate, its private `HotKey` reference is gone, too, and thus the event handler is effectively destroyed.

To try if this is the case, you could move the `hotKey` property to your `AppDelegate`. Then the property reference will be long-lived (until you quit the app, to be exact).

If that helps, I would strongly suggest you encapsulate the logic in a little helper. Could be stored as a singleton for simplicity.

```
class HotKeyController {
    static var instance = HotKeyController()
    private init() { }

    var hotKey: HotKey? {
        didSet {
            hotKey.keyDownHandler = { [weak self] in
                NSApplication.shared.orderedWindows.forEach({ (window) in
                   print("woo")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this in the view controller:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pressedLabel: NSTextField!
    
    private var hotKey: HotKey? {
        get { 
            return HotKeyController.instance.hotKey
        }
        set {
            HotKeyController.instance.hotKey = newValue

            guard let hotKey = newValue else {
                pressedLabel.stringValue = "Unregistered"
                return
            }

            pressedLabel.stringValue = "Registered"
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        register(self)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func unregister(_ sender: Any?) {
        hotKey = nil
        print("the hot key is ", hotKey?.keyCombo)
    }
    

    @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {
        hotKey = HotKey(keyCombo: KeyCombo(key: .j, modifiers: [.command, .shift]))
        print("the hot key is ", hotKey?.keyCombo)
    }
}
```

In the long run, you will want to implement `UserDefaults`-based hot key storage and restoration in the `HotKeyController`'s private initializer to make the settings "stick".